# Is there a way to factory reset a external hard drive that is not showing up in finder or disk utility on Mac?

Tags: mac, hard-drive

Is there a way to factory reset a external hard drive that is not showing up in finder or disk utility on Mac? I have tried many different cables and computers and the result is always the same. I have concluded that the disk is corrupted, is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: There may be more advanced disk tools for macOS which others may recommend. If there's nothing on the disk you need to recover, recycle it and move on. If the data is crucial, there are firms which will attempt to recover the material, but which may be costly, with varying levels of success. If you no longer need the disk, but it may have compromising data therein, you can find a recycling firm which will physically destroy the disk mechanism and the reduce the platters to small bits. If it is a SSD, however, a couple of whacks with a sledge hammer can pulverize the RAM chips to dust.

Comment: is it hard drive or SSD

Comment: Is the Disk Utility set to "Show All Devices"? What is the output from `diskutil list external`? I do not think corruption could prevent an external drive from appearing in the output from this command.

Comment: I set Disk Utility set to "Show All Devices" and it still doesn't show up. Also diskutil list external does nothing when I put it in terminal.

Comment: Then I would agree with the [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/694355) made by @Tetsujin, the enclosure holding the drive is dead. If not, then the drive itself is dead. In other words, there is a hardware failure.

Comment: What is the make and model of the external drive? If the drive was put in an enclosure, then what is the make and model of the enclosure?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know. It isn't on the drive or the enclosure.

Comment: Thanks all for your input, I think I might just take @IconDaemon's advice and pulverize it. The drive was cheap and there wasn't anything important on it, plus it sounds like fun. ;)

Comment: Would you care to make your comment an answer @IconDaemon - the OP can’t choose it since it’s just a comment now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you no longer need the disk, but it may have compromising data therein, you can find a recycling firm which will physically destroy the disk mechanism and the reduce the platters to small bits.

**If it is a SSD, however, a couple of whacks with a sledge hammer can pulverize the RAM chips to dust.**

Answer (score 0):

If the hard drive was not recognized by more than two computers, then either the cable is not functioning or the hard drive is corrupted. I have a faulty hard drive that can still be seen by my Mac, but cannot be formatted.

For your case, it seems there is something wrong with the internal hardware.

Comment: Ok,  those are my thoughts as well. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: … or the enclosure is dead. Corruption would not prevent the hardware from showing up.